# Powershell Rename-Item replace multiple naming parameters in one pass

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

I would like to replace a few filename parameters in one pass. Trying the following results in errors claiming the 'file already exists'. Is there a way to name multiple replace parameters in a single pass?

```
file | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "parameter1", "X" , $_.Name -replace "parameter2", "Y" }
```

Comment: Try `$_.Name -replace "parameter1", "X" -replace "parameter2", "Y"`

Comment: Perfecto @Theo, thanks. Submit this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Is file a command?

Comment: No file is a file, well in my case it's a variable naming a file @js2010

Comment: Then it would have a dollar sign in front of it.

Comment: uh thanks.. this question has already been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, my comment as answer.

You can daisy-chain `-replace`, so in this case

```
$_.Name -replace "parameter1", "X" -replace "parameter2", "Y"
```

<sup>Sorry for the short answer, but I'm on mobile now..</sup>